# How to connect to multiple wifi networks using Python?

Tags: connection, wifi

In my project I want to implement an acces control system using Python. I have a Spycam which is connected to a Raspberry Pi 4 using wifi protocol. I want to insert in my system an arduino which also communicates with the Raspberry on wifi protocol. 
I am using this code to connect to the camera([Simplest way to connect WiFi python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54479347/simplest-way-to-connect-wifi-python)), but how can I manage that my Raspberry could connect to both at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Arduino IDE. There is sample code that you can use to run an arduino in client mode. 
PLease give more infos about the arduino and its function.

Comment: Actual the problem what I don't mentioned that, the Raspberry is connected to the camera with TCP and in this case my Raspberry is the client and the camera is the source.

Comment: I assume that u have to configure the raspberry as host. Otherwise the arduino cant connect to it.

Comment: Yeah, actually I was wrong! I haven't describe well my problem! Actually, the raspberry pi is connected to a server with TCP connection....So in this case I could not manage this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Raspbi as host and connect the cam and arduino as clients.

Comment: Hy! As I actually mentioned in a comment, the communication between the raspberry and the camera is TCP/IP and the host is the camera. So maybe if i make an other connection throught wifi?